# How to map multiple same type loops under a function to the generated basic block in LLVM IR?

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api, llvm-codegen

If the loops are of the different type then I can easily identify them with the name but if there are multiple same type loops (say 5 `while` loops), how can I identify what basic block in the LLVM IR corresponds to which loop in the source code?

Manually it is easy to identify as we visit the code and the LLVM IR sequentially but I am looking how we can identify the same programmatically.

Example, I have the below source code in C:

```
int main()
{
   int count=1;
   while (count <= 4)
   {
        count++;
   }
   while (count > 4)
   {
        count--;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

when I execute the comand `clang -S -emit-llvm fileName.c` I got fileName.ll create with the below content:

```
; ModuleID = 'abc.c'
source_filename = "abc.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:w-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.0.23026"

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %count = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  store i32 1, i32* %count, align 4
  br label %while.cond

while.cond:                                       ; preds = %while.body, %entry
  %0 = load i32, i32* %count, align 4
  %cmp = icmp sle i32 %0, 4
  br i1 %cmp, label %while.body, label %while.end

while.body:                                       ; preds = %while.cond
  %1 = load i32, i32* %count, align 4
  %inc = add nsw i32 %1, 1
  store i32 %inc, i32* %count, align 4
  br label %while.cond

while.end:                                        ; preds = %while.cond
  br label %while.cond1

while.cond1:                                      ; preds = %while.body3, %while.end
  %2 = load i32, i32* %count, align 4
  %cmp2 = icmp sgt i32 %2, 4
  br i1 %cmp2, label %while.body3, label %while.end4

while.body3:                                      ; preds = %while.cond1
  %3 = load i32, i32* %count, align 4
  %dec = add nsw i32 %3, -1
  store i32 %dec, i32* %count, align 4
  br label %while.cond1

while.end4:                                       ; preds = %while.cond1
  ret i32 0
}

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!1 = !{!"clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final)"}
```

Now there are two basic blocks created for the given source file as `while.cond` and `while.cond1`, how can I identify which basic block is for which while loop in the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I attempt to answer, I just want to note that depending on the selected optimization level or the manually selected pass with `opt` that information might not be there or might not be as accurate (e.g. because of inlining, cloning, etc).

Now, the way to associate between low-level representations and source code is using debugging information (e.g. with the [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format). To produce debugging information you need to use the `-g` command-line flag during compilation.

For LLVM IR, if you take a look at the [`Loop`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Loop.html) API there are relevant calls like [`getStartLoc`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Loop.html#a615131659002c10601eef598d42d025e). So you could do something like this (e.g. inside the `runOn` method of a `llvm::Function` pass):

```
llvm::SmallVector<llvm::Loop *> workList;
auto &LI = getAnalysis<llvm::LoopInfoWrapperPass>(CurFunc).getLoopInfo();

std::for_each(LI.begin(), LI.end(), [&workList](llvm::Loop *e) { workList.push_back(e); });

for(auto *e : workList) {
  auto line = e->getStartLoc().getLine();
  auto *scope = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::DIScope>(e->getStartLoc().getScope());
  auto filename = scope->getFilename();

  // do stuff here
}
```

Moreover, for [`BasicBlock`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html), you can also use the debug-related methods in [`Instruction`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html) (e.g. `getDebugLoc`) and combine it with calls to other [`Loop`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Loop.html)'s methods such as `getHeader`, etc.

Also, note that there is a `getLoopID` method that uses an internal unique ID for each loop, but that is not always there and it's subject to the potential elisions I mentioned at the start. Anyhow, if you need to manipulate it, look at examples in LLVM source following the `setLoopID` method (e.g. in `lib/Transforms/Scalar/LoopRotation.cpp`).

Comment: Can you please help me with the header file that Ihas to include for `getAnalysis()` method

Comment: The `getAnalysis` method is inherited by the all the pass classes so it should be readily available. The `LoopInfoWrapperPass` is available from `llvm/Analysis/LoopInfo.h`. I think using `grep` or similar tools on the LLVM source tree helps a lot.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [this](https://github.com/compor/AnnotateLoops) repo. It annotates loops with a numeric ID. You can adapt accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I will update here as i implement it.

Comment: I am using llvm 4.0.1 and when I am trying to add the above code I am getting an error as "identifier `getAnalysis` is undefined". I tried to resolve but not able to.

Comment: If you're using it in a pass (using the `LegacyPassManager`) it should be readily available as this method inherited from the pass class (described [here](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.htm)). I don't have a working LLVM 4.0.1 setup, but I have compiled the earlier provided repo with current trunk (6.0.0). That part of the infrastructure hasn't changed.

Comment: Actually, I am not using it inside a pass, I am reading the basic blocks from the bit code file and processing the same.

Comment: That'd help if it was posted in the question; that is why SO policy requires posting some of your code. Anyhow, in the case of a standalone tool you'll have to generate the `LoopInfo` "manually". For that, you can have a look at the test suite in the `unittests` subdirectory,  e.g., the `Analysis/LoopInfoTest.cpp` where inside the `runWithLoopInfo` function, a standalone `LoopInfo` object for the passed `llvm::Function` is created using its constructed `DominatorTree`. I'm not sure if this test is available in 4.0.1, but it is in the current trunk (6.0.1).